# How can/should I exit a tty?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, tty

Occasionally I open a tty, using say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> (usually because I've done something silly and need to kill a program or recover in some way). After I've done so, I can switch back to that tty using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>, even while the GUI is "locked". This means that while the tty is available, anyone can walk up to my computer, while it is locked, and use it as me. This is, of course, less than ideal.

However, if I `logout` or `exit` this tty, I can no longer return to the GUI using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. The screen is black and unresponsive.

How can I get rid of the active login in these tty sessions without needing to reboot?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Comment: Are you using the proprietary Nvidia GPU drivers?

Comment: Yes, I don't get the same issue using Nouveau but I also only get 1/2 displays recognised and that one only at 1024x768

Comment: You should be able to go back with just alt-F2 (no ctrl needed).

Comment: I should be? Perhaps. Can I? No.

Comment: Tried to kill the bash process from the GUI?

Comment: I could probably do that, I think I saw a post describing how to get the PID of ttys. Will test that out.

Comment: Killing the bash process ended up doing the same as `exit` or `logout`. This was an issue on a work computer I've not used since so I never found a satisfactory resolution

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> should leave tty and take you back to GUI.

Comment: I think it is: `Ctrl + Alt + F1` ?    (Sorry, but the **old** way is `CTRL+ALT+...`, today it seems that `ALT+...` is also doing the job...)

Comment: It can be done with or without `Ctrl`.

Comment: @Luuk: It depends on where you are  switching *from* – X server maps the VT switching actions to Ctrl+Alt+Fx, while the tty itself maps it to just Alt+Fx.

Comment: Ah, that's why I always use `CTRL+ALT+...`, because that will always work 

Comment: This doesn't actually exit the tty, which is the whole point of my question

Comment: @alanocallaghan: Exiting the tty had already been answered by yourself, when you said: "if I `logout` or `exit` this tty"

Comment: Yes, and I explained why that was not a suitable option...?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> should work. This worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you read the context of the question it should be obvious that this is not a new answer and is something I had tried already